# Запуск скриптов Jmeter из Jenkins на JRE

Tags: java, тестирование, jenkins, jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Подскажите как запустить скрипт Jmeter из Jenkins с использованием JRE, а не JDK. В системных переменных прописан путь к JRE. Но при запуске из Jenkins включается JDK.

Comment: Как запускается JMeter скрипт? Для чего нужна именно JRE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Jenkins есть свои механизмы работы с переменными, например [вот здесь](https://medium.com/@mukeshsingal/access-jenkins-global-environment-variables-using-groovy-or-java-b5c1e6b53685):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или с помощью плагина [EnvInject](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/)

К сожалению в вашем вопросе недостаточно деталей (где задан путь до JDK, это [freestyle job](https://www.guru99.com/create-builds-jenkins-freestyle-project.html) или [Jenkins pipeline](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial), как именно запускается JMeter)

Самый простой способ - "жестко" прописать путь к JRE/bin/java в том месте, где вы запускаете JMeter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разработчики JMeter [рекомендуют использовать JDK](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#java_versions), поскольку при запуске с JRE он может работать с ошибками.

> Because JMeter uses only standard Java APIs, please do not file bug reports if your JRE fails to run JMeter because of JRE implementation issues.

Кроме того для записи HTTPS требуется JDK (keytool, который есть в нем):

> Although you can use a JRE, it is better to install a JDK as for recording of HTTPS, JMeter needs keytool utility from JDK.